# Intent setDataAndType as bitmap

Tags: android

I'm trying to use a method to crop a image. Exactly this method:

```
private void performCrop() {
    try {
        //call the standard crop action intent (the user device may not support it)
        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        //indicate image type and Uri
        cropIntent.setDataAndType(**HERE**, "image/*");
        //set crop properties
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        //indicate aspect of desired crop
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        //indicate output X and Y
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
        //retrieve data on return
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        //start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, 1234);
    }
    catch(ActivityNotFoundException anfe){
        Log.d("debugging","EXCEPTION");/*
        //display an error message
        String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support the crop action!";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();*/
    }
}
```

This line, asks for a Uri Data and String Type.

```
    cropIntent.setDataAndType(**HERE**, "image/*");
```

But I just want to put this bitmap

```
Bitmap fotoCreada;
```

as Data, but I don't know how to do it.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks.

## **EDIT**

Okay, this is my code right now:

There's a button. When you click it:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            Boolean isSDPresent = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
            if(isSDPresent) {
                //Creem carpeta
                File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/pic/");
                folder.mkdirs();
                //Recuperem data actual
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
                String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
                //Cridem a la camara.
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                resultingFile=new File(folder.toString() + "/"+currentDateandTime+".jpg");
                Uri uriSavedImage=Uri.fromFile(resultingFile);
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriSavedImage);
                //Començem activity
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 1888); 
            } else {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Issues while accessing sdcard.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
```

As you can see, it's calling startActivityForResult. Basically takes a picture, and I retrieve it on activityResult:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d("debugging",""+resultCode);
    if( requestCode == 1888 && resultCode == -1) { //-1 = TOT HA ANAT BE.
        Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(resultingFile.getPath());
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(90);
        Bitmap photoRotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(photo, 0, 0, photo.getWidth(), photo.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        this.fotoCreada=photoRotated;
        ((ImageView) myFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.fotoCapturada)).setImageBitmap(this.fotoCreada);
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(this.resultingFile.getPath());
            this.fotoCreada.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        performCrop();
    }
    if (requestCode == 1234 && resultCode == -1){
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
        Log.d("debugging",""+bitmap.getHeight());
    }
}
```

And as you can see from previous code, as I retrieve the bitmap, I call method performCrop. It's code, **now**, is:

```
private void performCrop() {
    try {
        //call the standard crop action intent (the user device may not support it)
        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        //indicate image type and Uri
        //cropIntent.setDataAndType(this.picUri, "image/*");
        cropIntent.putExtra("BitmapImage", this.fotoCreada);
        //set crop properties
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
        //indicate aspect of desired crop
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        //indicate output X and Y
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
        //retrieve data on return
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        //start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, 1234);
        Log.d("debugging","he acabat performCrop");
    }
    catch(ActivityNotFoundException anfe){
        Log.d("debugging","EXCEPTION");
        //display an error message
        String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support the crop action!";
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

But startActivityForResult from performCrop never ends up calling onActivityResult. Log cat says it just entered once, and should enter Twice. First one from the camera Activity and second from Crop activity.

```
-1
he acabat performCrop
```

Hope it's clear enough.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Bitmap` implements `Parcelable`, so you could always pass it in the intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("BitmapImage", bitmap);
```

and retrieve it on the other end:

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getParcelableExtra("BitmapImage");
```

However, if the bitmap exists as a file or a resource, its is always better to pass the URI or ResourceID of the bitmap and not the bitmap itself. Passing the entire bitmap requires a lot of memory. Passing the URL requires very little memory and allows each activity to load and scale the bitmap as they need it.

Comment: Okay. Sounds good. But my code isn't working. I'm going to edit my main post in few seconds. Check it out and give me a tip about how to solve it, please.

Answer (score 0):

Use Intent.putExtra.  A bitmap is a parceable, so it will work.  setDataAndType is used for URIs, but you aren't referencing a resource on the web or on disk.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to achieve now with my edited code.         cropIntent.putExtra("BitmapImage", this.fotoCreada);